# Swap json values with keys based on another json in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am completely new to python and I am stuck in this.

I have two json files with same keys and different values as below and all values are unique and not repeated.

```
srce_d1 = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val3', 'key4': 'val4', 'key5': 'val5'}

dest_d2 = {'key1': 'val4', 'key2': 'val7', 'key3': 'val1', 'key4': 'val2', 'key5': 'val8'}
```

I need to reorder/swap the values of dest_d2 as per the key,value pairs based on source_d1. To explain, in dest_d2, for key1, corresponding value is value1. I have to search for value1 among all the values and swap it with the value of key1 and so on until I get the common key value pairs and rest of the key values.

My modified dest_d2 should be like below in each iterations,

```
dest_d2 = {'key1': 'val4', 'key2': 'val7', 'key3': 'val1', 'key4': 'val2', 'key5': 'val8'}

dest_d2 = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val7', 'key3': 'val4', 'key4': 'val2', 'key5': 'val8'}

dest_d2 = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val4', 'key4': 'val7', 'key5': 'val8'}
```

And my final desired output json should be,

```
dest_d2 = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val7', 'key4': 'val4', 'key5': 'val8'}
```

And at the end I will have common key value pairs (key1,key2,key4) in both json files and the order of other key value pairs doesn't matter but I still need to have them.

Below is my code but it doesn't work at all.

```
    def verify_values(des_json_obj, src_json_file):
        file_val = open(src_json_file)
        src_json_val = json.load(file_val)
        output_json = {}
        for _,value1 in des_json_obj.items():
            for key,value in src_json_val.items():
                if value == value1:
                    output_json[key] = value
        return output_json
```

Comment: I do not fully understand what you want to happen. I am a bit confused by the `iterations` in your question - are those transitional stages that you imagine the code would produce *while it is working out the final solution*? What would the desired final output look like - precisely? Please edit your question *(edit link below question)* to add these details.

Comment: @gibberish, yes you are right, I expect the iterations to be part of the loop in which the swapping happens and I get the final desired output.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will do what you want:

```
srce_d1 = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val3', 'key4': 'val4', 'key5': 'val5'}
dest_d2 = {'key1': 'val4', 'key2': 'val7', 'key3': 'val1', 'key4': 'val2', 'key5': 'val8'}
res = {k:v if k not in source_d1 else source_d1[k] for k,v in dest_d2.items()}
print(res)
```

Example: https://trinket.io/python/cd86b81a14

Comment: This has nearly done it but still I am having the output as same as the source json.

The above code gives the output,


`{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4', 'key5': 'value5'}`


whereas my ideal expected output should be,


`{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value7', 'key4': 'value4', 'key5': 'value8'}`

Comment: @DeenadayalanS Can you explain the steps that lead to `'key3': 'val7'` ?

Comment: Below are the iterations to get the key-pair values,
`dest_d2 = {'key1': 'val4', 'key2': 'val7', 'key3': 'val1', 'key4': 'val2', 'key5': 'val8'}`
First iteration, The actual value of key1 as per source json, is val1. It is currently present in key3 and it has to be moved to key1, so I need to swap val1 with val4 which is in key1 and now my json would look like,
`dest_d2 = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val7', 'key3': 'val4', 'key4': 'val2', 'key5': 'val8'}`
And so on till I get the result
`dest_d2 = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val4', 'key4': 'val7', 'key5': 'val8'}`